# how to print string in a dictionary on swift?

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, character

How can I print type of largest number in this dictionary?

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var typeoflargest:String = " "
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for type in kind.characters {
        for number in numbers {
            if number > largest {
                largest = number
                typeoflargest = String(type)
            }
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
print(typeoflargest)
```

output:

```
25
S
```

why I got only first character "S" instead of "Square"?

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a clear question. It shows relevant code. It shows actual and desired output. What more do you down voters want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to be iterating the characters of the `kind` string. Just do the following:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var typeoflargest:String = ""
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            typeoflargest = kind
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
print(typeoflargest)
```

Output:

> 25
>   Square

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

let maximum = interestingNumbers
    .map{ type, numbers in return (type: type, number: numbers.max()!) }
    .max(by: { $0.number < $1.number })!

print(maximum.type, maximum.number)
```

Explanation:

First, get the maximal element of each category. Do this by iterating the dictionary, mapping the values from arrays of numbers to maximum numbers (within their respective arrays), yielding:

```
[
    (type: "Square", number: 25),  // 25 is the max of [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
    (type: "Prime", number: 13),   // 13 is the max of [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
    (type: "Fibonacci", number: 8) // 8 is the max of [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
]
```

Then, get the maximal type/number pair, by comparing their numbers, yielding the result:

```
(type: "Square", number: 25) // 25 is the max of 25, 13, 8
```

Comment: @rmaddy I'm still tweaking it, I will when I have a more final answer